# Pass associated model id to another form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, associations

I have the following association setup

```
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :donations
end
```

in my donation controller i have campaign_id as a strong parameter. Now when creating a donation i would like to have the campaign_id available to save in that form, but better off in the controller somewhere im guessing as less open to being edited. To get from the campaign to the donation form i click a button

```
<%= link_to 'Donate', new_donation_path, class: 'big-button green' %>
```

as we are already using

```
def show
  @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
end
```

How can i get that id into my donations form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Basically, your **routes.rb** might look something like:

`resources :campaigns do
  resources :donations
end`

Your **controller** might look something like:

```
class DonationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_campaign

  def new
    @donation = @campaign.donations.build
  end

  def create
    @donation = @campaign.donations.create(params[:donation])

    # ... 
  end

protected

  def find_campaign
    @campaign ||= Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])
  end 
end
```

And your example **link**, something like...

`<%= link_to 'Donate', new_campaign_donation_path(@campaign), class: 'big-button green' %>`

Comment: thank you for your help, any idea what i do with my form_for route then? previously i had <%= form_for @donation, html: { id: 'payment-form' } do |f| %>

Comment: its ok i done <%= form_for[@campaign, @donation], html: { id: 'payment-form' } do |f| %>